# Regexp - поиск содержимого HTML тегов

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Здравствуйте!

Допустим, у нас есть HTML код:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hashcode</title>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table><tbody><tr><td><p>Hello!</p></td></tr></tbody></table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
...
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Нужно составить такой шаблон поиска, чтобы нашлось содержимое "`<table><tbody><tr><td><p>Hello!</p></td></tr></tbody></table>`". Т.е. то, что находится между тегами td.

Т.е., прощу говоря, суть в том, чтобы находилось содержимое тега.

Comment: повтор вопроса - Expresso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По поводу регулярок для HTML - можете [просмотреть этот пост](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). А если разумно подходить к решению вопроса, то использовать соответствующие DOM-парсеры, например, [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) или [phpQuery](http://habrahabr.ru/post/69149/).

Comment: Этот пост, хотя бы из-за популярности, давно уже пора перевести на другие языки

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь html парсером. Напрмер, [phpQuery](https://code.google.com/p/phpquery/downloads/list)

Answer (score 0):

```
"\<td\>\<p\>([\\w\\W\\s]*)\<\/p\>\<\/td\>"
```

как-то так это выглядело бы на java